# Destroying the current window and create a new one

Tags: c, winapi, window

I have a program that is written in WinAPI.
I have the Login Window, and after that, the actual program window.
I want to destroy the login window, and create the new window..

I've been using this :

Destroying the program :

```
    DestroyWindow(MainHwnd);
```

and the WndProc of the window (of MainHwnd's window):

```
LRESULT Client::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(msg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
    break;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(1);
    break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}
```

And the people here in StackOverflow told me in my previous question, that I a'int destroying the window currently, and I'm causing a Stack Overflow which ends where the window is destroyed (the program stills run - so it looks like everything is working as planed), but I do not want to use bad programing (specialy causing stack overflow to destroy a window haha)

So, how can I destroy a window correctly?

Also, some times, when I use `DestroyWindow(MainHwnd)` it gets inside both `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_CLOSE` (in the current WndProc I have posted above).. Is this related to the Stack Overflow problem ?

Btw - I also know how to use Windows Forms in #C, I'm trying to write something like :
`this.Close();` which closes the current window (maybe that makes my question more clear)...

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you have to return `return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);` and in `case wm_destroy` it is `PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;`

Comment: DestroyWindow is fine. How about an SSCCE instead of a description.

Comment: But someone told me here that `DestroyWindow` calls `WM_CLOSE`, and in `WM_CLOSE` I'm calling `DestroyWindow` again... isnt that an endless loop?

Also, whats SSCCE ?

Comment: No, DestroyWindow() causes WM_DESTROY to be sent.  An SSCCE is a small program that we can run that demonstrates the problem.  Pretty bizarre to use "MainHwnd" as the name the variable that stores a login window handle btw, did you even post the correct code?

Comment: MainHwnd is the name of the actual client, and theres a case I try to destroy it and open a new window...

Comment: @Amit This would be trivially easy to answer with an SSCCE. It baffles me that you conceal code from us in this way. Do you want help or not?

Comment: Thanks! Also, the program of my program that exited was because my WM_CLOSE and WM_DESTROY` were the opposite (so when it wanted to destroy the program, it also exited it).. All I did was switching betwen the WM_DESTROY and WM_CLOSE, and it fixed it! Thanks guys!  @DavidHeffernan

Comment: That makes no sense at all to me

Comment: `DestroyWindow(hwnd)` calls to `WM_DESTROY`, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From microsoft about the `WM_CLOSE`:

`An application can prompt the user for confirmation, prior to destroying a window, by processing the WM_CLOSE message and calling the DestroyWindow function only if the user  confirms the choice. By default, the DefWindowProc function calls the DestroyWindow function to destroy the window.`

So calling `DestroyWindow(hwnd);` or not is the same.

```
LRESULT Client::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            //DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;

        or

        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        default:
           return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

see an example [closing window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Basically is what i said.

valter

Comment: If so, then why some times when I call `DestroyWindow(hwnd)` makes my code get into `WM_DESTROY` which closes my app, or not destroy my window at all? (and in all the times, it's the same line of code exactly, at the same place!)

Comment: @Amit The normal way is to do nothing and let `return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);` do the job(as in my comment). Otherwise, if you explicitly call `DestroyWindow(hwnd);` you should return 0.

Comment: So not to have wm_destroy mentioned in my wndproc at all?

Comment: Amit claims to be calling DestroyWindow directly so I don't see how this applies.

Comment: Thanks! Also, the program of my program that exited was because my `WM_CLOSE` and WM_DESTROY` were the opposite (so when it wanted to destroy the program, it also exited it).. All I did was switching betwen the `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_CLOSE`, and it fixed it! Thanks guys!